# How to query Access field with number format of Currency or Percent?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have an Access db, and in a table I have this field:

```
Field Name: FieldA
Data Type: Number
Field Size: Double
Format: Percent
```

On the form, there's a textbox named tBD. The user enters a value, clicks Button1 and a query runs. The result is stored in a textbox named tV. Here's my code:

```
OleDbConnection conn = null;
conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=c:\\mydatabase.accdb");
conn.Open();

double bd = Convert.ToDouble(tBD.Text);

string sql = string.Format("SELECT Something FROM Table1 where [FieldA] = {0}", bd);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.HasRows == true)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        tV.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
    }
}
else
{
    tV.Text = "0";
}
```

When I look at FieldA in Access, it has values like:

-15.00%
-13.25%
-18.00%
-12.50%

I'm just not sure how to have the user format the value they enter in tBD.Text, and/or how to format it in the code so it makes sense in query.

Also, I'm having the same issue when the Data Type is Currency. How should the user format their entered value, and how do I format it within the code?

Any ideas?
Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT Something FROM Table1 where [FieldA] = {0:0.00%}", bd);
```

but it turns -15.00 into -1500.00% .. I'm just not sure what proper way is to format this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out .. had to change

```
double bd = Convert.ToDouble(tBD.Text);
```

to

```
double bd = Convert.ToDouble(tBD.Text)/100;
```

Access wants to see -.1325, not -13.25